# Using a condition in a while loop

Tags: php

I have this code

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=odesk', 'root', '123456');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,msisdn from new_r4 limit 1,10");
$sth2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT status from flag where id = 1");
$sth->execute();
$sth2->execute();

while ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result2 = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $flag = $result2['status'];
    $the_number = $result['msisdn'];
    $id = $result['id'];

    while ($flag == 0) {
        echo 'Waiting.......' . PHP_EOL;
        sleep(1);
    }
    //Part of the condition,just added
    while ($flag == 1) {
        echo $the_number . '   ' . $id .'  ' . PHP_EOL;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

which is a a cli script that displays some numbers from my address book if a certain condition is met.If a the flag is `0` then no number shall be displayed and when the flag is `1`,then display the number.

The problem is,i can't find the right condition to use after

```
while ($flag == 0) {
    echo 'Waiting.......' . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(1);
}
```

The `if` , `else` and `case` do not wait up until the flag is 1.

What condition can i use to get the script to display the numbers when `$flag == 1`?.

Comment: I think you should `while($result2 = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` then do your `if` on the flag, right?

Comment: That's not your real password, I hope?

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes,it is,on localhost.No one else connects to my database.

Comment: Basically I agree with hd. I think you need a while($exitcondition) that inside checks if $flag==1. I don't know if your exitcondition it's the result2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$result2` and `$result1`. Your `$flag` will always be the value `id = 1` because the `WHERE` clause never changes - so either `$flag` will always be either `1` or another value (from your question, it's going to always be another value). Either change your query to join the table, or query whilst in the while loop.

Assuming `new_r4.id` = `flag.id`

```
SELECT r.`id`, r.`msisdn`, f.`status`
FROM new_r4 r
LEFT JOIN flag f
ON r.id = f.id
LIMIT 1, 10
```

Change your code to become

```
while ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $flag = $result['status'];
    $the_number = $result['msisdn'];
    $id = $result['id'];
```

Now all you need to do is check `$flag` is equal to `1`, and you're golden.

```
if($flag == 1) {
   echo $this_number . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. The `while` loop isn't looping?

Comment: The problem with the code is that `if($flag == 0) {
   echo 'Waiting' . PHP_EOL;
}` will only wait for 10 seconds and then exit.I want it to wait until the flag is 1.

Comment: `$flag` will never be 1. `$flag` is the value, and always will be the value, of whatever `SELECT status from flag where id = 1` returns.

Comment: In my case,the flag changes with time.Can be 1 or 0.

Comment: There is no code to change `$flag`. I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish now.

Comment: Some external process is toggling the flag.

Comment: @hd I solved the problem using java threads.I found what i described in the official java tutorial so it wasn't hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The `while ($flag == 0) {` is infinite and will never break out ($flag never changes within the loop); so the rest of the code is never executed.

Why not just use a simple if/else statement ?

```
if($flag===1){
    echo $the_number . '   ' . $id .'  ' . PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo 'Waiting.......' . PHP_EOL;
}
```